# I get [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/media_rw/24A3-6FDF/hello.txt (Permission denied)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am not able to read the files from the USB drive which is connected to the android device using 7.1.1.
MY manifest file has all the permissions.

I get

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/media_rw/24A3-6FDF/hello.txt (Permission denied)

Here is my code in main activity 
 `public void ReadFileFromStorage()`
 {

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside ReadFileFromStorage");
 var mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
 UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
 var deviceList = usbManager.DeviceList;
        IEnumerable<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.Values.AsEnumerable();
        if (deviceIterator.Count() > 0)
        {
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.ElementAt(0);
            usbManager.RequestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            if (usbManager.HasPermission(device))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HasPermission");
                UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.OpenDevice(device);
                if( connection != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" connection is not null");

                    Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/media_rw/C227-875D/");
                    if (dir.Exists())
                    {
                        fileList = dir.ListFiles();

                        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "exception did not occur" + "directory exists", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dir exists");

                        if (dir.IsDirectory)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dir.Path);
                        }
                    }

                }

                var model = device.DeviceName;
                string inlne = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // read the contents of the file
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/media_rw/C227-875D/test/hello.txt"));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("no exception occured");

    }
```

}

Comment: you need runtime permissions. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting Samples are included at bottom of link. Loads of answer on SO too.

Comment: I have all the permissions during runtime. i am having hard time including my code

Comment: @NandiniNadig you still don't quite give enough information here. *What* is the error you receive? *What* did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @Jonathan. This is the error I get:

Comment: [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/media_rw/24A3-6FDF/hello.txt (Permission denied)
01-11 03:04:55.401 E/mono-rt ( 5309):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.28110580-fe63-4db0-96a8-22531e1d0520(intptr,intptr,intptr)
01-11 03:04:55.401 E/mono-rt ( 5309):   --- End of managed Java.IO.FileNotFoundException stack trace ---
01-11 03:04:55.401 E/mono-rt ( 5309): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/media_rw/24A3-6FDF/hello.txt (Permission denied)
01-11 03:04:55.401 E/mono-rt ( 5309):  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

Comment: @NandiniNadig you should the error in the original question, and format it as a code block so people can read it. Does it work if you use the regular .NET APIs? `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`? I don't know why you need to use `Java.IO` here.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers. I used ReadAllText and I get                                         UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
01-11 23:07:01.494 I/MonoDroid( 2923): System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/mnt/media_rw/24A3-6FDF/hello.txt".                                                             Even though the file is there

Answer (score 0):

Since Android M+ you need to request permission not only in Manifest but at runtime also. You can see how to do it with this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

The second this I see in your code you're using the device as USB host. You need to adjust your manifest for this. **Go carefully** with the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host). You'll need one more permission and the `uses-feature` tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did have requested permissions during runtime. it says I have permissions, but gives permission denied exception. Mu code is on c# though

Comment: The USb drive is automatically mounted on /mnt/media_rw/(USB dribe name) whic is "/mnt/media_rw/C227-875D"

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the xamarin tag. You should google permission denied exception or add some code so people could help you faster! And mention that you DO request the permission

Comment: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.WebFormsClient" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: okey, I edited my answer, I don't work with xamarin but I work with android, until there no xamarin pros here let's see if we can figure this out with the docs

Comment: Xamarin.Android is just Android. So getting this to work in C# should be the same as Java, just imagine some of the letters are lowercase and C# properties are `getX` methods. @NandiniNadig you still don't quite give enough information here. *What* is the error you receive? *What* did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I added all these permissions but no luck                                                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
 <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

Comment: Saw this thread on stack flow. According to this we cannot access the mnt/media_rw/ from android 6.0 onwards?                                                                         link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201169/how-app-can-access-files-on-usb-otg-storages-in-android-6-0-api-level-23-witho